# Why Nginx load balancer is not serving js/css files from nginx nodes?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, docker-swarm

I have load balancer with really simple config for domain.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://dev-admin;  
    }
}
```

```
upstream dev-admin {
    server ip1:8001;
    server ip2:8001;
    server ip3:8001;
}
```

***IMPORTANT:
Ip1, Ip2 and Ip3 are docker containers that are made by making docker swarm service.***

**Now when you open `ip1:8001` or any other ip2 or ip3 you got website and all is good. Website is from react build.**

On each node ip1, ip2 and ip3 i have nginx with this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

So when you try website on domain.com instead serving css or js files it is serving index.html response. So domain.com/static/some.js -> this shows in the response index.html content.

I have no idea what else to debug.

Help. Please.

Answer (score 0):

It turned, out I was missing `$uri/` on nodes config.

So it is:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```